# Hiding the virtual reality symbol and disabling controls

Tags: react-360

Is it possible to hide the vr symbol which appears until your mouse is over the vr view?

[image: vr symbol]

It doesn't seem possible to disable all controls. You can disable touch panning with disableTouchPanning on mobile and it still uses the device orientation.

```
  ReactVR.init(
    './index.bundle.js',
    document.body,
    options = {
        disableTouchPanning: true,
        hideFullscreen: true,
        hideCompass: true, 
    }
  );
```

(see https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/blob/master/ReactVR/js/VRInstance.js)

Thanks!

Comment: Which logo do you mean? I saw it only in favicon.

Comment: I mean the vr-symbol which appears until you go with the mouse over it. It is maybe not the reactvr logo, I'll rename it.

Comment: Sorry, can you send a screenshot? Because I have no idea what do you mean.

Comment: I added an image. How would you call it? Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I understand ;) But for me, it disappears without any action after less than half a second after opening an app. That's why I didn't remember it :) And sadly I have no idea now how to help you with that :/

Comment: Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found how to hide this icon - maybe a bit cheat way but seems works :D

In `index.html` header, I added:

```
    <style> div > div > div {display: none}</style>
```

Since it's 'cheat' I'm also not sure if it will work always but it's just idea, you can start from that point and check it ;)